# Active Directory - user not a member of a group they are in

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am getting a list of groups for a specific user using GetAuthorizationGroups, but when I check to see if that user is a member of these groups sometimes I get false. So how come tttt below is false?

```
var ADContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "");
var userIdentity = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

var groups = userIdentity.GetAuthorizationGroups().OfType<GroupPrincipal>();
foreach (var group in groups)
     {
         var tttt = userIdentity.IsMemberOf(group);

      }
```

Comment: maybe some caching issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have nested group memberships? GetAuthorizationGroups returns a [recursive list of group memberships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). I believe IsMemberOf checks for *direct* membership.

As an example, I create a GroupA. GroupB is a member of GroupA, and I am a member of GroupB:

GetAuthorizationGroups would return GroupA and GroupB

IsMemberOf(GroupB) will be true, because I *am* a direct member of GroupB

IsMemberOf(GroupA) will be false, because I am *not* a direct member of GroupB

Comment: Is it possible to get the groups that a user directly belongs to.. I guess I can filter out groups that return isMemberOf=false... but would there be a method that does that without the need to filter out..

Comment: GetGroups does not do any recursion (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getgroups?view=netframework-4.7.2)